# ActionScript operator as

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, urlloader

does anybody have a good explanation of the [as](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#as) operator?

On one hand it seems to me, that it is often better to use **as** instead of instantiating a new object.

But then there are situations, when this operator let's me down. For example when loading a text file in XML format through an [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html):

```
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    trace("completeHandler: " + loader.data);

    var x:XML = new XML(loader.data);
    trace("x=" + x);
}
```

Why do I have to use a constructor here? Why can't I say **var x:XML = loader.data as XML;** and save some memory?

Thank you for any insights!
Alex

Comment: try with var x:XML = new XML(loader.data);

Comment: Yes thanks, that was a typo in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as` evaluates whether a variable's type is a super class or subclass of another class.  It does not create a new object.  The difference to `is` being that while `is` returns a Boolean value, `as` returns either an object of the desired type, or `null`.  It is used for type casts.

See the [ActionScript documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#as).

A typical use case would be using a MovieClip on the stage, which is retrieved by instance name:

```
// This will not compile:
var d:DisplayObject = stage.getChildByName ("instance1"); 
d.gotoAndPlay (2);

// This will play the MovieClip from frame 2
var m : MovieClip = stage.getChildByName ("instance1") as MovieClip;
m.gotoAndPlay (2);
```

`stage.getChildByName()` always returns a DisplayObject, regardless if it's really a MovieClip, Sprite, Button, etc. So if you want to use any of class MovieClip's methods, you need to type cast to MovieClip first. This does not, however, create a new MovieClip but simply ensures that you are using the correct type.

Comment: +1  Also @Alexander Farber you can cast by the following notation. var m : MovieClip = MovieClip(stage.getChildByName ("instance1")); The difference here is if the cast is unsuccessful a runtime error will be thrown. In contrast the as operator would return null.

Comment: Thanks. Any explanation on why do I get null in my example: var x:XML = loader.data as XML;   ?

Comment: Naturally, loader.data isn't XML object (even if it contains xml text). If you write XML(loader.data), you are using top-level operator XML(), which gets text and creates XML object from it.